# Java threads for the beginner

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been trying to explain Java threading to a colleague who has never been exposed to multi-threaded applications, but apparently I'm not a very good teacher.

Can anyone recommend a good online or offline resource that can explain threading in a simple, step-by-step manner? I know it's a complex topic, but surely there exists an article, book, or other explanation that can result in an "Aha! I get it, finally!" moment.

Comment: the real *"Aha! I get it, finally!"* moment for me was years after I started using threads, when I read *"Java Concurrency In Practice"*. Best. Java. Book. Ever. (even better than the excellent *"Effective Java"*).

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: I agree, that book is excellent and I nearly recommended it.  I just can't quite bring myself to point a beginner to it (or *Effective Java*, for that matter). :)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Concurrency](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) lesson in Sun's Java Tutorials.  It's kind of big, but it's broken up nicely.

Comment: Since you have the same answer as I, it would be churlish not to upvote you lol... +1

Answer (score 2):

I would point him in the direction of the official tutorial, where this subject is discussed [here.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

It was the official java tutorial that got me started, and I'm not even a serious Java developer...

Answer (score 1):

apart from the offical sun tutorial you may check these out

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/The-Basics-of-Multiple-Threads-in-Java/

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-threads-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here is an old but good one, got me the Aha, I get it effect

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

After the simple tutorials, I *strongly* recommend getting Brian Goetz's book "Java Concurrency in Practice" if the colleague might pursue multi-threaded programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swing also check SwingWorker:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html